# .Net Regex replace text between 2 delimiters inclusive/exclusive delimiters with something else

Tags: .net, regex

```
Field1: Unknown1
Field2: Unknown2
Field3: Unknown3
```

In my case I want to exclude row starting with "Field2:" which is effectively start marker "Field2:" end marker "\n"  and replace with '' including delimiters.

Or what would be regular expression if I wanted to replace

```
Field2: Unknown\n  with Field2: SomethingElse\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the row entirely (assuming input is a string that has all the rows delimited with `\n`):

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, "^Fielt2:.*\n", "", RegexOptions.MultiLine);
```

To replace the row:

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, "^Field2:.*", "Field2: SomethingElse", RegexOptions.MultiLine);
```

Since `.*` grabs everything to the end of the line except the terminating line break, there's no need to use `$` to match the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, we can trivially use anchors to just match that line:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "^Field2:.*$", "Field2: SomethingElse");
```

Comment: You need to set `RegexOptions.Multiline`, or it won't work because otherwise `^` and `$` match at the start/end of the string instead of start/end of the line.